# Using react + hooks, how can i call/use "navigate()" after a async redux dispatch properly?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-hooks

When using **"await"** on **"dispatch(saveItem(item))"** it's not supposed to have any effct ,
meanwhile if i don't use the "await" both functions will run in the same time resulting a saved item but not a component rerender.

Although the state changes in the redux store the view doesn't,
whilst using the await actually waits for the dispatch to complete and then runs the navigation.

My main question is how to properly navigate after a redux dispatch?

```
import { useEffect, useRef, useState } from 'react';
import { useDispatch } from 'react-redux';
import { useNavigate, useParams } from 'react-router-dom';
import { useForm } from '../hooks/useForm';
import { getById } from '../services/itemService';
import { saveItem } from '../store/actions/itemActions';

export function ItemEdit() {
    const dispatch = useDispatch();
    const navigate = useNavigate();
    const [item, handleChange, setItem] = useForm(null);
    const itemId = useParams().id;

    useEffect(async () => {
        await loadItem();
    }, []);

    const loadItem = async () => {
        try {
            const item = await getById(itemId)
            setItem(item);
        } catch(err) {
            setErrMsg(err.name + ': ' + err.message);
        }
    };

    const onSaveItem = async (ev) => {
        ev.preventDefault();
        await dispatch(saveItem(item));
        navigate('/item')
    }

    return (
        <form onSubmit={onSaveItem}>
            <button>Save</button>
        </form>
    );
}
```

Comment: The proper way depends on your use case. If the dispatched action and navigation are independent then there's no need to wait for the asynchronous action to complete. If there is *some* dependency on the dispatched action then you can wait for it to complete/resolve before issuing the imperative navigation. Does the code in your snippet have a specific issue? Is something not working as expected?

Comment: First of all thank you for your answer :) .
the dispatch returns nothing, but when i put the "await" it still waits for the function to complete and only then runs the "navigate()" function. this results in proper rendering upon loading the required route's component. 

if you don't write the "await" the added or edited items will not be rendered.

that's what so weird for me about it

Comment: There may be issues occurring elsewhere. Can you include your redux code? This `saveItem` action creator and the state slice(s)/reducer(s) handling that action (*and any actions it may also be dispatching*)?

Answer (score -1):

You can try it this way:

```
dispatch(saveItem(item))
   .unwrap()
   .then(() => navigate('/item'))
   .catch(error => 'handle error')
```

It works for me.